# SQL Count and Group by derived logic (Db2)

Tags: sql, count, db2

This code works. However, I want to run it without the filter for `contract_No` and then it doesn't work:-(. I'm sure im missing a left join and some steps.

Basically I have Contracts and contract lines (same table - `Contract_repo`), and I want to create a grouping of contract lines based on how many payments they have had last 12 months (different table on another level - `Payments` - and then count contract lines per group and rolled up to `contract_No` level.

```
Select a.Contract_No,count (*) as "Active Contract Lines",
(select count(distinct b.Contract_Line_No)
 from Payments b
 where b.Contract_NO = 32778
 and b.Contract_Line_No=(
  select distinct 
   case when Count(
    Case when  MONTHS_BETWEEN((CURRENT DATE - 1 MONTH),c.Period) < 11 
    then 1 end
    )=0 
    then c.Contract_Line_No end
   )  
  from  Payments c 
  where c.Contract_No = b.Contract_No
  group by c.Contract_Line_No
 ) as "Contract_Line = 0 trx L12M"
from Contract_Repo a
where a.Contract_NO =  32778
and a.status = 1
group by a.Contract_NO
```

This is my desired output:

| Contract_No | Active Lines | Lines with zero trx | Lines with 12 trx |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | 1000 | 600 | 400 |
| 67894 | 100 | 10 | 90 |
| 101112 | 500 | 100 | 400 |

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance.

Comment: @Pommes Minimal reproducible example means, that you provide CREATE TABLE and INSERT INTO statements for both tables, explain the meaning of each column of each table, explain how these 2 tables are related to each other, and provide the result desired on data above. Please, edit your question accordingly.